# Insert триггер/правило Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Помогите сделать правило/триггер при вставке записи в таблицу. Триггер должен работать следующим образом:

```
IF (Условие) THEN
    INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(NEW.*);
    RETURN (Записать, вставленная выше)
END IF;

(Если не срабатывает IF, происходит обычный запрос INSERT, но в таблицу table_2)
RETURN NEW;
```

Таблица `table_2` наследует `table_1`. Триггер работает правильно, но он не возвращает запись, вставленную в таблицу `table_1`.

Создавал триггер вот так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON table_2 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_trigger()
```

Я в курсе что триггер должен возвращать запись из таблицы `table_2`. Мне самое главное, чтобы после `INSERT` запроса возвращался `id` вставленной записи.

Comment: `запроса возвращался id вставленной записи` верните значения `sequence` вед оно вам нужно

Comment: Желательно сделать так, чтобы наращивание костылей не уходило за пределы базы